# c#: Draw point in panel on click event

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in c#;

I use bitmap equal to the size of the panel and set it as background image of the panel. I want to update bitmap with `setpixel` the panel update too on click event. But It doesn't work when I click on the panel.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap bmp; 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            panel1.BackgroundImage = (Image)bmp;
            panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = (e.Location.X).ToString();
            bmp.SetPixel(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, Color.White);
            bmp.SetPixel((e.Location.X)+1, e.Location.Y, Color.White);
            bmp.SetPixel((e.Location.X)-1, e.Location.Y, Color.White);
            bmp.SetPixel(e.Location.X, (e.Location.Y)+1, Color.White);
            bmp.SetPixel(e.Location.X, (e.Location.Y)-1, Color.White);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you are trying to create a larger pixel look into `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp ) {  g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, 2, 2);  .....}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the panel. Call

```
panel1.Invalidate();
```

after having drawn on the bitmap.

---

If you use the `MouseMove` event you can also draw continuously:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        bmp.SetPixel(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, Color.Green);
        bmp.SetPixel((e.Location.X) + 1, e.Location.Y, Color.Green);
        bmp.SetPixel((e.Location.X) - 1, e.Location.Y, Color.Green);
        bmp.SetPixel(e.Location.X, (e.Location.Y) + 1, Color.Green);
        bmp.SetPixel(e.Location.X, (e.Location.Y) - 1, Color.Green);
        panel1.Invalidate(
            new Rectangle(e.Location.X - 1, e.Location.Y - 1, 3, 3));
    }
}
```

Make sure to draw only when the left mouse button is pressed and invalidate only the rectangle on the panel that has changed to minimize flicker.

---

A note on `Invalidate()`: Invalidate does not update the image immediately. Instead it tells Windows that we want an update. Windows then determines whether the invalidated region is visible. There could be be another window on top of it, it could be off-screen or the window could be minimized. Then it waits until the application is idle. This prevents the accumulation of too many unprocessed events (e.g. MouseMove). This means that `Invalidate` might skip some updates. This is good since it avoids lag.